# Missing GraphFactory

Tags: android, eclipse, achartengine, android-library

I'm trying to get "a chart engine" up and running. 
My problem is that I dont have the GraphFactory class, after including the achartengine-1.0.0.jar to eclipse (I'm making an android 4.1 app).
I have been trying to look around on the forum for awnser on how to get the GraphFactory for about an hour, but it simply gives way to many hit when I search on it.

My question is how do I get the GraphFactory added to my eclipse (where can I download the jar file including it)?

I know the quistion have probably been awnsered before, and I'm sorry that my searching skills are not good enough to find it on the forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AChartEngine doesn't contain any class called `GraphFactory`.
However, there is one class called `ChartFactory`.

Also, for example code for showing you how to use AChartEngine, I suggest you take a look at [these](http://www.achartengine.org/content/goodies.html) instructions.

Comment: Thanks for the help, dont know how I missed the correct class name

Answer (score 0):

I to am trying the same thing.

I assume your using the example from here https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/create-graphs

My guess is that you have to make your own class but if anyone else can tell us that would be great.

Edit: i found a good example here. http://xebee.xebia.in/2010/08/31/exploring-android-charting-and-graphs-solutions/ go to the AChartEngine example.

I hope that helps :)